# cannot implicitly convert type int

Tags: c#

plz help me
cannot implicitly convert type `int`

```
var dt =  check.Search1(EmailTextBox.Text);
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5r143L6.png

Comment: TableInfoTableAdapter checkin = new TableInfoTableAdapter();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           
            dt = checkin.Searching1(EmailTextBox.Text);
            if(dt.Rows.Count!=0)
            {
                LabelInfo.Text = "ایمیل یا تلفن شما قبلا ثبت گردیده است";
                LabelInfo.Visible = true;


            }
            else
            {

Comment: Please put the code *as text* into the question, having reduced it to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are calling expects a nullable int, whereas you are passing the Text property of a textbox, which is a string. Even if the textbox contains as string that can be converted to an int, it's still a string.

Some languages (such as JavaScript) will automatically convert values for you. C# is strongly typed, and requires you to do the conversion yourself.

You should also validate the contents of the textbox, as if the user didn't type something that could be converted to an integer, any attempt to convert will fail.

Look at the Convert.ToInt32() and Int32.TryParse() methods